# SQL Order By via Junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a simple setup for related products One-to-Many. My DB has two tables:

`product` table with `id, name` columns and a junction table `product_assignments` with `product_id, related_id, order` columns.

I need to get all the related products, sorted by `order` column

```
SELECT * FROM `products` LEFT JOIN
`related_assignments` `ra` ON `products`.`id` =
`ra`.`product_id` WHERE `id` IN (412, 1663, 1928) ORDER BY
`ra`.`order` DESC
```

I see no errors and I am getting all three records (412, 1663, 1928) but sorted by their id's, not by order field.

How do I sort them with one SQL-request?

Product

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | name  |
+------+-------+
|  412 | Watch |
| 1663 | Book  |
| 1928 | Phone |
| 2000 | Cup   |
+------+-------+
```

Related

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| product_id | related_id | order |
+------------+------------+-------+
|       2000 |        412 |     1 |
|       2000 |       1663 |     2 |
|       2000 |       1928 |     0 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Sample data would really help.  The most likely reason would be that there is no match.

Comment: As I told I can get all the records that matches conditions but they aren't in the right order.

Comment: What's your expect order? maybe you need to provide some data for us

Comment: How does `order` look like for each ID? Maybe it just coincidentally defines the same order as the IDs.

Comment: Since you are using LEFT JOIN it might be that those ids are not in the related_assignments table and there is no field to order by. I recommend using JOIN instead.

Comment: No, it's not. I've tried manually change order to see any difference.

Comment: You aren't selecting the order field though, just products.*. Is this intentional?

Comment: My mistake, I've edited to SELECT *

Comment: @bewell I write an answer you can try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sample data and expected result you seem to need to use `ra.related_id` be the join condition instead of  `ra.product_id`,

when you use `Left join` on `products.id =ra.product_id` it only return `id = 2000` rows data. but your where clause use `id IN (412, 1663, 1928)`, that will let `ra.order` all be `null`, so that the `order by ra.order` will do notthing.

```
create table products(
   id int,
   name varchar(50)
);



insert into products values ( 412, 'Watch');
insert into products values (1663, 'Book ');
insert into products values (1928, 'Phone');
insert into products values (2000, 'Cup  ');


create table Related(
   product_id int,
  related_id  int,
   `order` int
);

insert into Related values (2000,  412 ,1 );
insert into Related values (2000, 1663 ,2 );
insert into Related values (2000, 1928 ,0 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` LEFT JOIN
`Related` `ra` ON `products`.`id` =
`ra`.`related_id` 
WHERE `id` IN (412, 1663, 1928) 
ORDER BY `ra`.`order` DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7de03/6/0)**:

```
|   id |  name | product_id | related_id | order |
|------|-------|------------|------------|-------|
| 1663 | Book  |       2000 |       1663 |     2 |
|  412 | Watch |       2000 |        412 |     1 |
| 1928 | Phone |       2000 |       1928 |     0 |
```

Comment: Looks like I've used wrong field to connect tables. Thanks

Comment: @bewell Glad to help